# “Invalid parent value” error for non-random variable in JAGS

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, rjags

I am running a hierarchical Bayesian model with simulation data just to see if the Bayesian model can retrieve the parameter values I set for generating the simulation data. And when I was running the Bayesian model in JAGS (with rjags), it returned an “Invalid parent value” error for one of my parameters called ***comp.p***. However, as the parameter ***comp.p*** in my model is not a random variable and simply defined by a deterministic expression, I just cannot quite see how it can be possible to have “Invalid parent value” error for a non-random variable.

Therefore, I was just wondering if anyone has met the same problem or may know in what scenario this might happen.

Here is part of my JAGS code. As my code is pretty long, I only put the part I think it's related but will be happy to update with more code if the information is needed.

```
model {

##Priors setting here###

 for (k in 1:year){

##Long process model here###

   for(j in 1:ngrids) {
      N[j,1,k+1]~dpois(u2[j,1,k]+u4_frag_post[j,1,k])
      N[j,2,k+1]~dpois(u2[j,2,k]+u4_frag_post[j,2,k]) 
      N[j,3,k+1]~dpois(u2[j,3,k]+f.f[j,k]*trans.F.4*u2[j,4,k]) 
      N[j,4,k+1]~dpois(u2[j,4,k])

      NTotal[j,k+1]<-N[j,1,k+1]+N[j,2,k+1]+N[j,3,k+1]+N[j,4,k+1]     
    }
  }

##End of process model######

#### Data model ############

  for (k in 2:year){
    for (i in 1:n.comp) {
      comp.p[i,1,k]<-N[comp.ind[i],1,k]/NTotal[comp.ind[i],k]  
      comp.p[i,2,k]<-N[comp.ind[i],2,k]/NTotal[comp.ind[i],k]
      comp.p[i,3,k]<-N[comp.ind[i],3,k]/NTotal[comp.ind[i],k]
      comp.p[i,4,k]<-N[comp.ind[i],4,k]/NTotal[comp.ind[i],k]

      y.comp[i,2:5,k]~dmulti(comp.p[i,1:4,k],y.comp[i,6,k])   
    }
  }
##End of data model######
}
```

where all the parameters are non-negative real values

And the error message I obtained is:

```
Error in node comp.p[4,4,8]
Invalid parent values
```

which looks odd to me, as it means that it run okay for the first 7 loops but start to have problems on the 8th, even when they are based on the same expression.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Assure that every `NTotal` is different from zero, since they are at the denominator of a fraction. It looks like `NTotal[comp.ind[4],8]` might be zero.

Comment: Thank you very much, Nicola. I had a try, indeed it was the cause. I didn't notice that it can generate NaN with 0/0!